# Can't close the "share a link to this question" popup on review page

Tags: bug, status-completed

While reviewing posts today on the review page, I upvoted a question and got the "share a link" dialog. It would not go away. Clicking "close" did nothing, and reviewing other posts did nothing.

[image]

**Update:**
This happened again today, and I noticed that it seems to fail when more than one of these is open at a time (I ignored the first one and tried to close the second - failed). Perhaps that has something to do with it?

**Update:**
Reproduced again today, with excatly two of these open and on-screen. Clicking close in the second one closed the first one, and the close button then became useless.

**Update:**
When multiple questions are opened in the "review" state, upvoting one of them causes the box to appear in the others.

**Update:**
This seems to apply to the "Vote to close" dialog as well (one dialog, several questions "opened" for review) - clicking vote makes it look like it is submitting, and it never goes away (but it does submit the vote).

**Update:**
After closing one like this and reaching this buggy state, no more of these will open.

Comment: I'm wondering whether it would be more productive to post this bug on the [meta-Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/). A quick search didn't seem to find any other reports of this problem.

Comment: I think I will do that. I just tried to reproduce it on SO, and got slightly different bugs (First link box didn't appear until the second up-vote, at which point the second also appeared).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it, should be fixed in the next 24 hours